# If $f(r)\ne 0$, then exits $\delta>0$ such as $f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in [r-\delta,r+\delta]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Given $ f\in C[a,b]$ and $r\in(a,b)$. Prove that

If $f(r)\ne 0$, then exits $\delta>0$ such as $f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in [r-\delta,r+\delta]$.

My ideas is

As $f$ is continuous, $f(r)\ne0$, let $\epsilon= \frac{\left| {f(r)} \right|}{2}>0$, then exits $\delta>0$ such that
$$ \forall x : \left| x-r \right| <\delta \Rightarrow \left| {f(x)-f(r)} \right|<\frac{\left| {f(r)} \right|}{2}$$
We have $\left| {f(r)} \right|-\left| {f(x)}\right|\leq \left| {f(x)-f(r)} \right|<\frac{\left| {f(r)} \right|}{2} \Rightarrow 0<\frac{\left| {f(r)} \right|}{2} < \left| {f(x)}\right|.$

So I just have $f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in (r-\delta,r+\delta)$.

Help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your proof is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction, assume that there exists a sequenc $r_n \to r$ such that $f(r_n)=0$. By continuity, $f(r)=0$.

Anyway, your idea is essentially correct, and it is based on the fact that a continuous function has in a whole neighborhood the same sign as it has in the center of the neighborhood.